# lay myself down vs lie down

Tags: grammar

I've seen a lot "I may just go lay myself down on the bed" in movie.
I think they are same. Are they right?
"I'd like to lay myself down on the bed."
VS
"I'd like to lie down on the bed."

"Laying myself down on the bed is great feeling."
VS
"Lying down on the bed is great feeling."

Comment: Lay is an active verb, while lie is a passive verb. After you lay (physical movement) on the bed, then you lie (passive, non-movement) on the bed.

Comment: He lay the book on the table [active verb]; He lies on this bed at night. [active verb]. There is nothing passive about these verbs.

Comment: @RonMaupin - I think maybe you mean "transitive" and "intransitive", but "You lay on the bed" is only correct in the past tense.  In the present tense you have to lay *something else* on the bed.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, lay is the past of lie.

Answer (score 3):

**AmE speech typically mixes up lay and lie**.

"I may just **go lie down on the bed**"; the **action of a person** is: lie down

"I will **lay your clothes on the bed** when they dry.": **what you do to a thing**

In colloquial American speech, lay down is used for lie down. It is marked as dialectal and probably uneducated speech. (Uneducated speech does not mean I am judging it here. I am not.)

Lying down on a bed can make you feel better if you are not feeling well.

Laying your clothes out on the bed on a chair is a useful way make your mornings easier.

Please note the verb forms:

I lie, I lay [yesterday], I have lain [gerund: lying]

I lay, I laid [yesterday], I have laid [gerund: laying]

There are many sites on the Internet with exercises for these verbs, which many people do mix up, even native speakers.

Comment: Anyway, can't I put "myself" in that sentence? Is it weird or unnatural ?

Comment: Which sentence? What do you mean?? I lie down, you lie down. BUT: I lay the book on the table.

Comment: I may just go lie myself down on the bed

Comment: I would like to lie myself down on the bed.

Comment: Lying myself down on the bed is great feeling.(me)

Comment: @이관우 - No, you don't usually "lie yourself".  *Lie* is intransitive (it does not take an object), whereas *lay* is transitive, which is what Lambie explained.

Comment: @이관우 lie yourself down on the bed in the sentence you posted might possibly be a colloquial thing. Anything is possible with Hollywood and the way people speak. It is not standard.