# "Lay" in Rogue Legacy Prince's Journal, Entry #1

Tags: lie-lay-lain-laid

Prince's Journal, Entry #1.

> Tonight I will get a headstart over my brothers and sisters, and set forth on my quest while they lay asleep.

[image: LAY]

From what I understand, the verb after **while** should be used in its present tense because previously the prince used Future Simple tense. The usage of Future Simple and then Past Simple would be perplexing to say the least.

I see two reasons why **lay** was used there:

1. Prince made a typo.
2. The archaic present tense of **lie** was **lay**, or some other flavor of [REDACTED].

So please tell me, why was **lay** used here? Did I miss something?

EDIT: I'm well aware of the difference between *lay* and *lie*, it's just that I didn't expect to see such a mistake in a widely acclaimed game.

Comment: It's an error, albeit a common one, even for native speakers. It should read _while they lie asleep_. Even that sounds a little awkward - _while they sleep_ sounds better. _Head start_ should also be written as two separate words, and the more common preposition to use with it is _on_ (not _over_: you get a _head start **on**_ someone or an _advantage **over** someone_).

Comment: Many people still distinguish the transitive verb _lay_ from the intransitive _lie_. many do not: this is one way in which English has been changing. Many of those who still distinguish them like to castigate other people's English as _wrong_ or _an error_.

Comment: There is nothing *archaic* about this at all. to lie asleep (simple present tense)//lay asleep (simple past tense). However, as Type1A said, it should be: while they lie asleep. I have already answered this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162253/lay-myself-down-vs-lie-down/162256#162256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is an error by the game's writer; it should be "lie". Confusion between "lay" and "lie" is a very common mistake for native English speakers. I wouldn't be surprised if the two words merge entirely in another hundred years or so -- it seems a little silly to have two similar but separate words for such similar concepts.

That said, that phrase feels a little odd to me. It's meant to read as if it's slightly archaic, since the Prince's journal is from hundreds of years ago, but it doesn't quite work.  I would have recommended that the writer either say *while they sleep* or *while they lie abed* (if you want to be a bit poetic and old-timey).

Comment: It does sound imitation archaic to my ears too (+1).

Answer (score 3):

The person doing the writing simply does not know grammatical English. "Lie" means to be passive and unmoving whereas "lay" means to take a specific kind of action. The whole point is that the prince is active while his siblings are not.

Why do I believe that the writer does not know English grammar? Because just a few sentences earlier he wrote "he has sent my siblings and I on a quest" There is no way that "I" is a typo for "me."

There is no reason to believe that producers of video games devote substantial resources to ensuring good grammar.

Comment: Further complicated because the word **lay** forms both the present tense of one verb (they lay bricks) and the past tense of another (they lay down). Moreover, **lie** has another past tense form **lied**, depending on the sense.  It's a grammatical spider's web.

Comment: Not a coincidence: historically _lay_ is a causitive of _lie_ (as well as its past), as _fell_ is of _fall_, and _raise_ of _rise_. This kind of formation is no longer productive in English, though.

Comment: Ahh the ablaut. Thanks RS and CF for the historical insight.

Comment: To be fair, substituting *I* for *me* when attempting to sound high-class and proper is super common among native english speakers who are otherwise very well spoken and grammatically accurate. We tend to think of "me" as being a more casual word and it takes a moment of thought to say, "No, no, it's correct in this context".  I don't think it's fair to say from this alone that the person doesn't know grammatical english.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym He sent my siblings and me on a quest. The "I" is an English mistake."me" is not more or less casual. He saw me, not He saw I. And using "I" is not an attempt to sound "high class". It's just jarring. And a red-flag.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I know it's a mistake, but it's very common for otherwise grammatical people who are trying to sound serious and formal to say things like "...to my family and I". It happens all the time. I'm not saying "and me" is in fact casual, but to a lot of people it feels like it's less formal, and they switch to "I" when they shouldn't. It isn't a red flag of bad grammar skills. I've heard it many times from the likes of senators, scientists, and priests. It might be the single most common grammar mistake in English.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym It definitely is an indicator that mistakes in grammar are truly mistakes in grammar rather than typographical errors. "Lie" to "lay" could possibly be a typographical error; there is no way "me" to "I" is a typographical error. Nor is the union of the sets of scientists and priests coextensive with the set of those who use English well. There is a difference between social esteem and linguistic knowledge.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Grammatical people? Now, that's new to me. [funny]